# fastest way to do triangular matrix vector multiplication in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

A is n*n upper triangular matrix,x is n*1 vector, is there any faster way to do Ax in matlab than A is full, since it should need n*(n+1)/2 multiplications rather than n^2 multiplications.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can improve the performance because any solution making use of the zeros adds to much overhead. The first idea to increase the performance would be to exclude the quarter containing only zeros, I did this using this function:

```
@(x,y)[x(1:end/2,1:end/2)*y(1:end/2);x(end/2+1:end,:)*y]
```

This way 50% of the multiplications by zero are skipped.

And compared it to the standard way:

```
@(x,y)(x*y)
```

Using random input data:

```
@(n)triu(rand(n))
@(n)rand(n,1)
```

The results show that simply multiplication is faster.

[image]

Exection Times (mean)

```
                 @(x,y)(x*y)    @(x,y)[x(1:end/2,1:end/2)*y(1:end/2);x(end/2+1:end,:)*y]
           2        0.000015        0.000027
          10        0.000015        0.000028
         100        0.000023        0.000041
        1000        0.000454        0.003433
        2000        0.003002        0.014185
        3000        0.006505        0.032233
        4000        0.011401        0.057172
        5000        0.018567        0.089489
       10000        0.076099        0.351794
```

To summarize, you are doing 50% useless calculations, but with MATLAB's very efficient implementation of matrix multiplication. It is probably the best option.

Comment: I am wondering if to separate the matrix A into n row vectors(each row has a length of n-i+1, name them A1, A2,..., An), then repeat the x vector n times in a style each one is the latter n-i+1 elements of x(name them x1, x2, ...,xn), and then do the inner production,get the result of A1.x1, A2.x2,...,Anxn, I am not sure if this wll be helpful, especially I have  a large number of such unchanged A matrix(so I can prepare all the A1 to An beforehand), with the same random x at a time.

Comment: @georgeandrew: Doing it on a row-by-row basis would be much slower. 1) You slice it in to small problems which kill any multi-threading. 2) You add a lot of control overhead.

Comment: thank you very much! I believe you have very through study on this, I can tell from your plots.

Comment: Do you think the same conclusions can be valid in R? I'll try to your benchmarking there.

Comment: Never used r, but I guess the results will be the same.